# How to add letter label to numeric values in a tibble?

Tags: r, tibble

i have a column in my tibble with values 10 10 10 20 20 20 20 30 30, I want to create a new column as follows: 10a 10b 10c 20a 20b 20c 20d 30a 30b.

Comment: `mydf$newcol <- paste0(mydf$oldcol, rep(letters[1:3], 3))`

Comment: If any of the three answers helped you please consider upvoting/accepting them

Answer (score 0):

Here's an economical solution with `dplyr` and `data.table`:

First convert to dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30))
```

Now transform in `dplyr` using `data.table`'s function `rowid` and the built-in constant `letters` (for lower-case letters) subsetted on `rowid` (credit to @Henrik):

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  mutate(x_new = paste0(x, letters[rowid(x)]))
# A tibble: 9 x 2
      x x_new
  <dbl> <chr>
1    10 10a  
2    10 10b  
3    10 10c  
4    20 20a  
5    20 20b  
6    20 20c  
7    20 20d  
8    30 30a  
9    30 30b
```

Comment: Given that you are happy to load `data.table`: `paste0(x, letters[rowid(x)])`

Comment: @Henrik Oh yes, absolutely, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and concise solution using only **dplyr**.

```
# import library
library(dplyr)

# data
df <- data.frame(id = c(10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30))

# solution
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% # grouping by id 
  mutate(
    alpha_id = letters[1:length(id)], # create alpha id 
    new_id = paste0(id, alpha_id) # new_id = id + alpha_id
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% # ungroup
  select(-alpha_id) # dropping staging variable.
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
     id new_id
  <dbl> <chr> 
1    10 10a   
2    10 10b   
3    10 10c   
4    20 20a   
5    20 20b   
6    20 20c   
7    20 20d   
8    30 30a   
9    30 30b
```

Comment: Nice but basically exactly the same thinking (just with `dplyr`only)

Comment: You said it right, thought was similar, key point is **lesser libraries lesser dependencies...**, Also, i always try to create lesser variables where possible as all objects are **in-memory** here.

Comment: Thanks for bringing in notice... just updated the field name.

Answer (score 0):

### BaseR

```
df$x2 <- ave(df$x, df$x, FUN = function(.x) paste0(.x, letters[seq_len(length(.x))]))

   x  x2
1 10 10a
2 10 10b
3 10 10c
4 20 20a
5 20 20b
6 20 20c
7 20 20d
8 30 30a
9 30 30b
```

---

### dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30))
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(x2 = paste0(x, letters[row_number()]))
# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   x [3]
      x x2   
  <dbl> <chr>
1    10 10a  
2    10 10b  
3    10 10c  
4    20 20a  
5    20 20b  
6    20 20c  
7    20 20d  
8    30 30a  
9    30 30b
```